# substituting for a router in a closed virtual environment

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-esxi, linux-networking

Just a quick question, how can I create a substitute for a router in a vmware esxi environment containing several windows and linux servers on two seperate subnets?

I would like to use redhat as the server doing the routing between the subnets and I don't want to do any NAT or masquerading.

Thanks,
Matt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplest setup, enable IP Forwarding on the redhat machine, configure both ethernet adapters to have IPs on their respective networks.  Set the client machines default gateways to point to whichever redhat IP is on the same subnet.

Now if you want this to work with external routers, you'll need to setup some static routes.  That can get complicated fast.

Comment: To enable IP forwarding, set "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" in /etc/sysctl.conf and reboot.  (Or "echo 1 >> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"

Comment: I've enabled the net.ipv4.ip_forward though I can only seem to ping the ip address of the "router" on the other subnet. No routing appears to be taking place. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: iptables is likely on and not allowing you to forward packets from one interface (subnet) to the other interface (subnet).  You need to add a FORWARD filter.  Have a look at this iptables tutorial: http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch14_:_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables

Comment: Nope, no iptables enabled.

Comment: My apologies. Seems like it is now working to verify the original test. Thanks all. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another virtual switch, assign two virtual interfaces to your RedHat VM and put each on either virtual switch and route accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done. Though how does the "routing accordingly" take place.

Comment: You should clarify your question then, but the routing happens as described by mfarver below.